# Pandas left join with different dimensions

Tags: python, pandas

I am still new to pandas and have the following problem. I want to merge two tables together but they have different dimensions.

I have 2 data frames.

```
Date:         Order Num.:      More Stuff:     Even more ... 
01.01.2021    123              asdf            ...
01.01.2021    124              fdsa            ...
02.01.2021    127              foo             ...
...           ...              ...             ...
```

The second one contains more information on the Order Numbers and have additional shipping numbers.

```
Order No.:    Shipping Num.:
123           111112
123           111113
123           111114
124           111171
124           ...
```

The result should be a left join on order number with the final table looking something like:

```
Date:         Order Num.:      Shipping Num.:      More Stuff:     Even more ... 
01.01.2021    123              111112              asdf            ...
01.01.2021    123              111113              asdf            ...
01.01.2021    123              111114              asdf            ...
02.01.2021    124              111171              fdsa            ...
...           ...              ...                 ...             ...
```

I tried using `df_result = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='Order No.:', right_on='Order Num.:', how='left')`and a few variations of that but the extra columns get lost in the process. How do I go about this?

Comment: What is your pandas version? Can you provide reproducible input constructors? I don't reproduce it

Comment: @mozway I had a typo and I didn't notice it up until now. It works as intented now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside the fact that you seem to have inverted the column names, I don't reproduce your issue:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='Order Num.:', right_on='Order No.:', how='left')
```

output:

```
        Date:  Order Num.: More Stuff: Even more ...  Order No.:  Shipping Num.:
0  01.01.2021          123        asdf           ...       123.0        111112.0
1  01.01.2021          123        asdf           ...       123.0        111113.0
2  01.01.2021          123        asdf           ...       123.0        111114.0
3  01.01.2021          124        fdsa           ...       124.0        111171.0
4  02.01.2021          127         foo           ...         NaN             NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to merge it like:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='Order No.:', right_on='Order Num.:', how='left')
```

Note that it does not use pd.merge but uses the `merge` method of df1.